# Jquery checkbox does'n work (checked and unchecked)

Tags: jquery, checkbox

It's doesn't work ( Why? Can anybody explain, please

```
function checkBox()
    {
        if($('.checkbox').prop('checked', true))
        {
            $('body').css('background','yellow');
        }
        else if ($('.checkbox').prop('checked', false))
            $('body').css('background','blue');
    }
```

Comment: html
`<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/7rpeL2gu/4/

Thats the answer
HTML:

```
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.checkbox').on('click', function(){
    checkBox( $(this) );
  });
});

function checkBox($this){
  if( $this.prop('checked') ){
      $('body').css('background-color','yellow');}
  else{
      $('body').css('background-color','blue'); }
}
```

P.S. Your code does not work, because `$(input).prop('checked', true)` - set `input` to `checked`, but `$(input).prop('checked')` give you `input.state` of checked.

P.P.S read this https://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: if i create function such as function checkBox(), i have mistake 
`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: wait a second, i re-write code now for function calling

Comment: snx ( You helped me a lot

Comment: @Viktory try that way

Comment: You forget to include jquery - i update your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4kzvnyky/1/

Comment: in ur html add between `<head> ... </head>` that row   `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`  - it added jQUery library to your site

Answer (score 1):

`.is()` - Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments.

```
   if($('#checkbox').is(':checked')){
      $('body').css('background','yellow');
    }
    else{
      $('body').css('background','blue');
    }
```

Comment: please make sure your event is triggered or not